# UIApplication errors after converting application to Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I am getting the following errors after updating my app to the latest syntax and I have no idea why. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
 if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.background {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector(Selector("backgroundRefreshStatus"))
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector(#selector(UIApplicationDelegate.application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)))
        var pushPayload = false
        if let options = launchOptions {
            pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpened(launchOptions: launchOptions)
        }
    }
    if application.respondsToSelector(#selector(UIApplication.registerUserNotificationSettings(_:))) {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    }
```

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnZqN.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you have code to share with us, please don't post it as image. You can add it to your post and [format it as code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: First of all, don't post screenshots, post code. Second of all, your code doesn't seem to be updated to the latest syntax.

Comment: @FelixSFD If i just added the code you wouldn't be able to see the errors

Comment: @vadian I updated my project to Swift 3 and got these errors

Comment: Seems your code may have something that Swift migrator does not like, try convert it again with Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax... If it fails, you need to convert your code, huge parts, manually by yourself. For example `respondsToSelector(_:)` is renamed as `responds(to:)` in Swift 3.

Comment: @OOPer That selector thing is perfect! Thanks! What about the ambiguous references?

Comment: One fix may tell you that you need many other fixes. Please try to fix your issues by yourself. Create an empty project with Xcode 8 and comparing two AppDelegates would suggest you many things. (You may need to replace all method headers.) Fixing the issues one by one, Xcode would give you better suggestions.

Comment: @OOPer Do you have a specific answer for just these two issues?

Comment: I have something in mind, but I don't want to show it as an answer which does not run in actual apps. Wait for someone who can help you in a better way.

Comment: @OOPer What do you mean? I really need some help here. Can you please share you answer as a comment?